# How to create a single function in controller?

Tags: controller

I have these codes in my 2 visualforce pages:

```
<apex:page standardController="mycontroller" docType="html-5.0" standardStyleSheets="false" extensions="EditDelete" action="{!editItems}" sidebar="false">

   <div class="slds-box slds-box_xx-small">
        <p class="slds-text-align--center"><apex:pageMessages /></p>
   </div>
```

the same codes is applied to delete page.
currently, I am using 2 methods in  mycontroller to return the apex message.

```
public PageReference editItems(){
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'Please click the Edit Batch button to update.')); 
    return null;
}
public PageReference deleteItems(){
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'Please click the Edit Batch button to delete this item.')); 
    return null;
}
```

Is it possible to merge these 2 into 1 method? How will I change the codes in visualforce pages also?

Comment: need to know how you are calling this from VF to merge the methods you need to pass an argument and based on that message string will be different

Comment: hi @AvijitChakraborty , actually they are buttons from a custom object. Edit button and Delete Button.

Comment: @Mae can you show the code that calls these two methods?

Comment: Im sorry, I edited my question... there are 2 visualforce pages actually that overrides the object page edit and delete button.

Answer (score 1):

First, as an aside, don't specify returning a PageReference if you don't intend to redirect:

```
public void editBatchItems(){
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'Please click the Edit Batch button to update.')); 
}
public void deleteBatch(){
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'Please click the Edit Batch button to delete this item.')); 
}
```

---

In order to specify a message, you'd have to pass a parameter in, which you *can* do, but it might not be worth it. Here's what that might look like:

```
public transient Integer messageId { get; set; }
public void showMessage() {
  String[] messages = new String[] {
    'Please click the Edit Batch button to update.',
    'Please click the Edit Batch button to delete this item.'
  };
  ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, messages[messageId]));
}
```

There's other ways to do this, but ultimately, as you can see, you end up writing *more* code, not less; you'd also have to modify your buttons:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!showMessage}" value="Edit">
  <apex:param name="theMessageId" value="0" assignTo="{!messageId}" />
</apex:commandButton>
```

Ultimately, you're not really saving much unless you had to do this for a bunch of buttons, and realistically, it'd still probably be a bad idea. For a simple one-line method, it's realistically not worth the time to try and and be "[DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)" about it.